# ng-model property is undefined in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I've got some textareas with `ng-model="award.questions.propertyName"`. I need to put those input values to an array with such structure:

```
questions: [{
 key: value,
 key: value,
 ...
}]
```

but `console.log` return this values as undefined when I submit my form.
When I defined questions as object `{}` it's works like a charm and all values is good, but when i turn it in array nothing works.

View

```
<textarea name="short-Description" ng-model="award.questions.shortDescription"></textarea>
<textarea name="consumer" ng-model="award.questions.consumer"></textarea>
<textarea name="advantages" ng-model="award.questions.advantages"></textarea>
```

Controller

```js
$scope.award = {
  questions: [{
    shortDescription: $scope.shortDescription,
    consumer: $scope.consumer,
    advantages: $scope.advantages,
  }],
};

$scope.onSubmit = (award, awardForm) => {
  $scope.data = angular.copy(award);
  console.log($scope.data);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the situation. The `textarea`s are inside `ng-repeat`? Can you show the `form` you refer to (`onSubmit`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `award` variable has no `question` property.

You should change your code to:

```
<textarea name="short-Description" ng-model="award.questions[0].shortDescription"></textarea>
<textarea name="consumer" ng-model="award.questions[0].consumer"></textarea>
<textarea name="advantages" ng-model="award.questions[0].advantages"></textarea>
```

Or with `ng-repeat` if you have multiple questions:

```
<div ng-repeat="question in award.questions track by $index">
  <textarea name="short-Description" ng-model="question.shortDescription"></textarea>
  <textarea name="consumer" ng-model="question.consumer"></textarea>
  <textarea name="advantages" ng-model="question.advantages"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: only first element has been added  with that ng-model

Comment: if you have multiple questions, use `ng-repeat` as i mentioned

Answer (score 0):

`award.questions` is an array - so it's got no property named `consumer` or any of your other variables (note it's `questions` not `question`). Use `[0]` to get the first item in the array.

```
<textarea name="short-Description" ng-model="award.questions[0].shortDescription"></textarea>
```

With this kind of format however, it's easier to use one object. View:

```
<textarea name="short-Description" ng-model="award.question.shortDescription"></textarea>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.award = {
  questions: {
    key: value,
    ...
  }
}
```